# I need to take tricky integral without Fourier transform

Tags: integration, vectors, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

$$
\int_{0}^{inf} \dfrac{\vec{v} [\vec{n} \times \vec{n} \times \dfrac{d\vec{v}}{dt}]}{|\vec{r}-\vec{a}|} \delta(\vec{r}-\vec{a(t)}) \,dr
$$
I took the inmtegral with Fourier transform, but teacher said to find way to do it without it. I tried to write explicitely cross-cross product in spherical coordinates but this gave no benefit (don't want to write with LaTeX 3 lines of useless from my point of view fromula). Is there any other elegant way to achieve result?

Comment: Is the integral over a scalar $r$ or over a vector $\vec{r}$? It also looks like you have a vector ($\vec{v}$) multiplying another vector ($\left[\vec{n}\times\vec{n}\times \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\right]$). What does that mean? Is it supposed to be a dot product? What is $\vec{n}$? Are $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{a}$ velocity and acceleration?

Comment: r is scalar, you are right there is dot product, so overall it is scalar function under integral. A is not acceleration, it is some vector. n is a normal vector

Comment: The triple cross product seems ambiguous. Do you mean $(\vec{n}\times\vec{n})\times\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$ or $\vec{n}\times\left(\vec{n}\times\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\right)$? The first of these two is zero. How do all of the quantities in the integrand ($\vec{v}$, $\vec{a}$, $\vec{r}$, and $\vec{n}$) depend upon the scalar integration variable $r$?